# How to make this table? Or how to stack fix columns like this?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I have to make this type of chart using `highcharts-vue`, the problem is that it is not a default chart type like line or column. I'm not sure how to stack fix columns like this and make it only color the one with data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `column-stacked` chart. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
   enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
   lineWidth: 0,
    offset: -30,
    categories: ['3Q19', '2Q18', '1Q18', '4Q17', '3Q17']
  },
  yAxis: {
  title: {
     text: ''
    },
    categories: ['1st', '2st', '3st', '4st'],
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    reversed: true,
    labels: {
     formatter: function () {
       var cat = ['1st', '2st', '3st', '4st'],
         value = cat.includes(this.value);

       return value ? this.value : '';
      },
      y: 40
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      groupPadding: 0.05,
      color: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#000',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'A',
    data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    data: [{
     y: 1,
      color: '#C4D8FE'
    }, {
     y: 1,
      color: '#C4D8FE'
    }, 1, 1, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    data: [1, 1, {
     y: 1,
      color: '#C4D8FE'
    }, {
     y: 1,
      color: '#C4D8FE'
    }, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'D',
    data: [1, 1, 1, 1, {
     y: 1,
      color: '#C4D8FE'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zdgukqjs/